# Receiving SMS Message Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

My Kotlin app send and receive messages but the `Toast.makeText()` does not work when I receive message. I've included my files below. All the solutions I've tried so far does not work.

**QUESTION:** How do I make the `Toast.makeText()` to work.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver
        android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**SmsReceiver.kt**

```
package com.example.sendmessege

import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.telephony.SmsMessage
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast


class SmsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

private val TAG: String = SmsReceiver::class.java.getSimpleName()
val pdu_type = "pdus"


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
override fun onReceive(
    context: Context?,
    intent: Intent
) { // Get the SMS message.
    val bundle = intent.extras
    val msgs: Array<SmsMessage?>
    var strMessage = ""
    val format = bundle!!.getString("format")
    // Retrieve the SMS message received.
    val pdus = bundle[pdu_type] as Array<Any>?
    if (pdus != null) { // Check the Android version.
        val isVersionM = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
        // Fill the msgs array.
        msgs = arrayOfNulls(pdus.size)
        for (i in msgs.indices) { // Check Android version and use appropriate createFromPdu.
            if (isVersionM) { // If Android version M or newer:
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(
                    pdus[i] as ByteArray,
                    format
                )
            } else { // If Android version L or older:
                msgs[i] =
                    SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdus[i] as ByteArray)
            }
            // Build the message to show.
            strMessage += "SMS from " + msgs[i]?.originatingAddress
            strMessage += " :" + (msgs[i]?.messageBody) + "\n"
            // Log and display the SMS message.
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: $strMessage")
            Toast.makeText(context, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
 }


}
```

am I missing something? or Is their another way to write the `onReceive()` function to make the `Toat.makeText()` to work?.

Comment: I found the following article be helpful. But it still has errors that I'm working on, https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-phone-sms-course/Lesson%202/2_c_sms_messages.html

Comment: Did you make sure that you have permission to receive messages?

Answer (score 1):

**In the Manifest.xml**

No need to add the category in receiver

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".SMSReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

- You can try out this function

  ```
  private fun receivemsg() {
           var br  = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
               override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
                   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
                      for (sms:SmsMessage in Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(p1)){
                          Toast.makeText(applicationContext,sms.displayMessageBody,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                      }
                   }
               }
           }
           registerReceiver(br, IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
       }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that you are using runtime Sms-receive permission too with Sms-Send permission.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_MMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS),
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS)
        } else {
            enableSmsButton()
        }
```